# Hide 'View Item' link in preview window in sharepoint asset library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide 'view Item'  link in pop up (shown below) from preview window. I uploaded a video in asset library. As per requirement users should not download videos from library. How to hide or disable view item link.  Any help?[image: Hide 'View Item' link]

Answer (score 0):

This link might use.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/7445/programmatically-create-digital-asset-library-in-sharepoint.aspx

Dharmendar.

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.